# Providing a default value for an Entity Reference Field using Views Bulk Operations

Tags: feeds, views

I have a content type called 'Schools' and a CSV spreadsheet that has columns for information such as School Name, Location, Telephone etc...

Using Feeds I can import the information on the 111 Schools to individual pages.

Furthermore I have a field on the 'Schools' Content type that is an entity reference field to an entity  (an entity form - that lets the user contact the school - of widget type 'Select list')

However when I import the school data with my feed the 'entity reference' 'select-list' field defaults to 'none' and the 'Contact form' does not display. Furthermore the entity reference field does not let me set a default value for the 'select list'.

I don't want to go through 111 schools to do this manually. While [the previous question on this subject calls for some code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27655/default-value-for-entity-reference-field)...that I do not yet understand...

Therefore is there a way to essentially set a default value for my entity reference ... Perhaps '[Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)' is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

Views > Create New View > Content type 'Schools'

Format > Table

Add Fields > Title

Add Fields > Bulk Operations (Content) > Bulk Operations > Modify Entity Values > 'Your Entity Reference Field' > Skip Confirmation Step > Show Token Values

done - navigate the views bulk operations URL, select all of your nodes and apply the changes ... You might need to adjust the pager options in the view to see all of your nodes, and also disable the feeds importer while you adjust the nodes associated with it...